# Typescript | Argument of type '{ username: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, axios

I have this simple service that takes and endpoint and execute a HTTP_CALL. This is it below:

```
export const updatePassword = (data: {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}): HttpResponse<string> => {
  const { username, password } = data;
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.POST,
    url: endpoint.UPDATE_PASSWORD({
      username,
      password
    })
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

But I get this error:

```
Argument of type '{ username: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I am not sure what is his problem since I am doing the exact same thing a few lines above and I do not get an error.

In case you need the endpoint I am hitting, here it is:

```
  UPDATE_PASSWORD: (username: string) => `${prefix}/${username}/password`,
```

Also, HttpRespone is an extension on `AxiosResponse` Generic, and instance is an extension of `AxiosRequestConfig`, along with some custom generics.

//UPDATE. This is the converted way:

```
export const updatePassword = (data: { username: string }): HttpResponse<string> => {
  const { username } = data;
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.POST,
    url: endpoint.UPDATE_PASSWORD(username)
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

Comment: Your `UPDATE_PASSWORD` accepts parameter of type `string` and you are passing object. Instead send only `username` or modify your `UPDATE_PASSWORD` to accept `object` as parameter.

Comment: I converted it that that, as you suggested, see description, but now I am not sure, It will update the password. Can you explain it a little bit better?

Comment: - You need to pass the password field too. Modify your `UPDATE_PASSWORD ` parameter to make it accept an object or you can make it to accept two parameters, one for username and another for password.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is JSON.stringify instead to convert your javascript object into JSON text.

Comment: No, this is actually very wrong. Services have no reason to do JSON.Stringify. They need to be pure. Pass data as the get it, or send them in the same way.

Comment: I do not see any obstacles to the use of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `UPDATE_PASSWORD` accept two parameters - one for username and another for password.

```
UPDATE_PASSWORD: (username: string, password: string) => `${prefix}/${username}/password`,

export const updatePassword = (data: {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}): HttpResponse<string> => {
  const { username, password } = data;
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.POST,
    url: endpoint.UPDATE_PASSWORD(username, password)
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```